# Damping harmonic oscillation code with python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I don't know that how make the code  the three graph in damping harmonic oscillation model,
`[X - t(time)], [V(velocity) - t(time)], [a(acceleration) - t(time)]` graph

i can make the `[X - t(time)]` graph
but i don`t know how to make another graphs..

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# mx'' = - bx' - kx

x_0 = 3

v_0 = 0

y_0 = np.array([x_0,v_0])         # first array 


def Euler_Method(f,a,b,y0,step):

  t = np.linspace(a,b,step)

  h = t[1] - t[0]

  Y = [y0]

  N = len(t)

  n = 0

  y = y0

  for n in range(0,N-1) :

    y = y + h*f(y,t[n])

    Y.append(y)

    n = n+1  

  Y = np.array(Y)

  return Y, t




def harmonic(y,t) :

  k = 50

  m = 200

  b = 20  # drag coefficient

  a = (-1*k/m)*y[0] - (b/m)*y[1]   # x'' = a,  y[0] : first position

  v = y[1]                         # v = first velocity : y[1]

  f = np.array([v,a])

  return f

  


a = Euler_Method(harmonic, 0, 100, y_0, 100000)

X = a[0][:,0]

t = a[1]

plt.plot(t,X)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you just take the derivative of X to get V and A?

```
V = np.diff(X)
A = np.diff(V)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3)
fig.suptitle('Vertically stacked subplots')
ax1.plot(t, X)
ax2.plot(t[1:], V)
ax3.plot(t[2:], A)
plt.show()
```

Gives,

[image]

Comment: thanks!!!! i don`t know the function `np.diff` and why you take the V,A to t[1:], t[2:], but i get study your code. very thank you

Comment: It's necessary to do that becasue when you take the diff of an array, the resulting array will have one less element than your original array (since, you are doing a subtraction of every consecutive element). So V will have 99 elements if X has 100. So in order to plot it, you need to reduce time by one element too. And if your problem is solved by the problem, please accept the solution and mark your question as answered.